# NaN produced from division of values put a Vector

Tags: matlab

Below is some MATLAB code which is inside a loop that increments `position` every cycle. However after this code has run, the values in the vector `F1` are all `NaN`. I print `A` to the screen and it outputs the expected values.

```
    % 500 Hz Bands
    total_energy = sum(F(1:(F_L*8)));
    A =  (sum(F(1:F_L))) /total_energy %% correct value printed to screen

    F1(position) = (sum(F(1:F_L))) /total_energy;
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: do the following: `F1(position) = (sum(F(1:F_L))) /(total_energy+eps);`

Comment: Is this inside a function?  Is F1 an output variable?

Comment: excellent, that worked. Cheers Parag

Comment: Disagree @Parag's comment.  That's sort of hack is no substitute for understanding the problem.

Comment: Well... whatever I have written above (i.e. always adding `eps` when dividing) is a good practice. However, I don't see how that will help you. I am wondering, how can you get correct values for A and `NaN` for F1. RHS of both is the same. You are missing some detail.

Comment: Yes thats inside a function and F1 is an output.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I will write a detailed answer, but see my next comment. That is why I didn't convert that into an answer.

Comment: @user1845029: Did you look at the value of F1 right before the function exits?

Comment: so `F` and `F_L` are input arguments for the function?

Comment: I suspect `F_L` changes with `position`.  This calculation would be very uninteresting if it doesn't.

Comment: I also suspect this could be vectorized using `cumsum`.

Comment: What is `F` anyway?  usually energy is not the sum, but the sum-of-squares

Comment: The function is quite large so I didnt include it all. The mean of F1 is a output. Using +eps has fixed the problem. Does anybody know why it did?

Comment: @user1845029: Seems like `total_energy` was `0`... but everywhere?  That seems hard to believe.

Comment: F is the FFT of a window of data. Im using F_L separate that into frequency bands. Position increments for every window analyzed.

Comment: Yeah I think you should be using sum-of-squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `F_L = position * interval`, I suggest you use something like:

```
cumulative_energy_distribution = cumsum(abs(F).^2);
positions = 1:q;
F1 = cumulative_energy_distribution(positions * interval) ./ cumulative_energy_distribution(positions * 8 * interval);
```

sum-of-squares, which is the energy density (and also seen in Parseval's theorem) is monotonically increasing, so you don't need to worry about the energy going back down to zero.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, if you divide zero by zero, you get a `NaN`. Therefore, its always better to add an infinitesimal number to the denominator such that its addition doesn't change the final result, but it avoids division by zero. You can choose any small value as that infinitesimal number (such as 10^-10) but MATLAB already has a variable called `eps`.

`eps(n)` gives a distance to the next-largest number (whose precision is same as `n`) which could be represented in MATLAB. For example, if `n=1`, next double-precision number you could get to from 1 is `1+eps(1)=1+2.2204e-16`. If `n=10^10`, then the next number is `10^10+1.9073e-06`. `eps` is same as `eps(1)=2.2204e-16`. Adding `eps` doesn't change the output and avoids the situation of `0/0`.

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't so simple.  Neither `num / (denom + eps(1))` nor `num / (denom + eps(denom))` are correct.  The first will change the output (contrary to your last sentence) if `denom` is close to `eps`.  The second avoids that, but will still overflow for `denom == 0`, `num != 0`.  Of course, hiding errors like division by zero isn't likely the right approach anyway.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, you are absolutely correct. I just wrote by keeping a general scenario in mind. Thank you for pointing out the flaws.